# How to create the Sub route file in scala and how to access that route?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.3

Is there any way to create the sub route file and tell me how to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main `routes` file, you can add a line like:

```
/foo -> foo.Routes
```

If you then add a `foo.routes` file with the following content:

```
/bar/:id controllers.Application.bar(id)
```

then all `/foo/bar/:id` URI's will be routed to the `controllers.Application.bar` function.

Comment: Its working fine.Now  I updated my project with another route.thanks lot

Answer (score 1):

Create new **admin.Route** in your **conf** file

```
conf/routes:

GET /index                  controllers.HomeController.index()

->  /admin admin.Routes

GET     /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
modules/admin/conf/admin.routes:

GET /index                  controllers.admin.HomeController.index()

GET /assets/*file           controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/lib/myadmin", file)
```

please try this link  [SBTSubProjects](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects)